# If found keywords print line else print python

Tags: python, if-statement, search

i am trying to write a code where i can search certain keywords from different files ; if found print line and hostname ; else not found print "Test Passed" and host name

```
Hostsfile.txt 
router1
router2

router1.txt

not ready is ready 
reset me if required
blah
blahhh blahh

router2.txt

blah
blahhh blahh
```

Code

```
hosts = open((hostsfile) , "r")
keys = ['Not Ready','RESET']
hosts = [hosts for hosts  in (hosts.strip() for hosts in open(hostsfile)) if hosts]
for host2 in hosts:
  f = [f for f in (f.strip() for f in open("router1.txt")) if f]                  
    for line in f:
        for keywords in keys:
            if keywords in line:
                print (line)
                file2.write (line)
            elif:
                file2.write("Test Passed")
```

it return the correct search results but for all lines where it doesnot find keywords print "Test Passed", the output i am looking for is

```
router 1
not ready is ready 
reset me if required

router 2 
test passed
```

Comment: just made it a string ; just wrote as an example ; so please pardon any of such errors ; just need to find a logic which can be implemented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this what you are looking for

it will only print passed once if it passed

```
hosts = open((hostsfile) , "r")
keys = ['Not Ready','RESET']
hosts = [hosts for hosts  in (hosts.strip() for hosts in open(hostsfile)) if hosts]
for host2 in hosts:
  f = [f for f in (f.strip() for f in open("router1.txt")) if f]   
  testpassed = True
    for line in f:
        for keywords in keys:
            if keywords in line:
                print (line)
                file2.write (line)
                testpassed = False
   if testpassed:
     file2.write("Test Passed")
```

Comment: @Saadi381 Sorry I forgot to add testpassed = False in the code , just edited the code now , it should work